# ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,64) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,64)

Tags: python, neural-network

I am following the instructions to make a neural network from the book "Neural Networks from Scratch in Python" and I have gotten to the SGD optimizer with learning rate decay, but when I try to add momentum to it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn.py", line 142, in <module>
    optimizer.update_params(dense1)
  File "nn.py", line 110, in update_params
    layer.biases += bias_updates
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,64) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,64)
```

For me this seems to be an error with NumPy, but I barely have experience with it and I don't understand this error well.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data
import nnfs
import pickle

nnfs.init()

class Layer_Dense:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))
    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases
        self.inputs = inputs
    
    def backward(self, dvalues):
        self.dweights = np.dot(self.inputs.T, dvalues)
        self.dbiases = np.sum(dvalues, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        self.dinputs = np.dot(dvalues, self.weights.T)
        
class Activation_ReLU:
        def forward(self, inputs):
            self.output = np.maximum(0, inputs)
            self.inputs = inputs
        def backward(self, dvalues):
            self.dinputs = dvalues.copy()
            self.dinputs[self.inputs <= 0] = 0

class Activation_Softmax:
    def forward(self, inputs):
        exp_values = np.exp(inputs - np.max(inputs, axis=1, keepdims=True))
        probabilities = exp_values / np.sum(exp_values, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        self.output = probabilities
    def backward(self, dvalues):
        self.dinputs = np.empty_like(dvalues)
        for index, (single_output, single_dvalues) in enumerate(zip(self.output, dvalues)):
            single_output = single_output.reshape(-1, 1)
            jacobian_matrix = np.diagflat(single_output) - np.dot(single_output,single_output.T)
            self.dinputs[index] = np.dot(jacobian_matrix, single_dvalues)

class Loss:
    def calculate(self, output, y):
        sample_losses = self.forward(output, y)
        data_loss = np.mean(sample_losses)
        return data_loss

class Loss_CategoricalCrossEntropy(Loss):
    def forward(self, y_pred, y_true):
        samples = len(y_pred)
        y_pred_clipped = np.clip(y_pred, 1e-7, 1-1e-7)
        if len(y_true.shape) == 1:
            correct_confidences = y_pred_clipped[
                range(samples),
                y_true
            ]
        elif len(y_true.shape) == 2:
            correct_confidences = np.sum(
                y_pred_clipped * y_true,
                axis=1
            )
        negative_log_likelihoods = -np.log(correct_confidences)
        return negative_log_likelihoods
    def backward(self, dvalues, y_true):
        samples = len(dvalues)
        labels = len(dvalues[0])
        if len(y_true.shape) == 1:
            y_true = np.eye(labels)[y_true]
        self.dinputs = -y_true / dvalues
        self.dinputs = self.dinputs / samples
class Activation_Softmax_Loss_CategoricalCrossEntropy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.activation = Activation_Softmax()
        self.loss = Loss_CategoricalCrossEntropy()
    def forward(self, inputs, y_true):
        self.activation.forward(inputs)
        self.output = self.activation.output
        return self.loss.calculate(self.output, y_true)
    def backward(self, dvalues, y_true):
        samples = len(dvalues)
        if len(y_true.shape) == 2:
            y_true = np.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
        self.dinputs = dvalues.copy()
        self.dinputs[range(samples), y_true] -= 1
        self.dinputs = self.dinputs / samples
class Optimizer_SGD:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=1., decay=0., momentum=0.):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.current_learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.decay = decay
        self.iterations = 0
        self.momentum = momentum

    def pre_update_params(self):
        if self.decay:
            self.current_learning_rate = self.learning_rate * (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))
    
    def update_params(self, layer):
        if self.momentum:
            if not hasattr(layer, 'weight_momentums'):
                layer.weight_momentums = np.zeros_like(layer.weights)
                layer.bias_momentums = np.zeros_like(layer.biases)
            weight_updates = self.momentum * layer.weight_momentums - self.current_learning_rate * layer.dweights
            layer.weight_momentums = weight_updates
            bias_updates = self.momentum * layer.bias_momentums - self.current_learning_rate * layer.dweights
            layer.bias_momentums = bias_updates
        else:
            weight_updates = -self.current_learning_rate * layer.dweights
            bias_updates = -self.current_learning_rate * layer.dbiases
        layer.weights += weight_updates
        layer.biases += bias_updates
    def post_update_params(self):
        self.iterations += 1

X, y = spiral_data(samples=100, classes=3)

optimizer = Optimizer_SGD(decay=1e-3, momentum=0.5)
dense1 = Layer_Dense(2, 64)
activation1 = Activation_ReLU()
dense2 = Layer_Dense(64, 3)
loss_activation = Activation_Softmax_Loss_CategoricalCrossEntropy()

for epoch in range(10001):
    dense1.forward(X)
    activation1.forward(dense1.output)
    dense2.forward(activation1.output)
    loss = loss_activation.forward(dense2.output, y)
    predictions = np.argmax(loss_activation.output, axis=1)
    
    if len(y.shape) == 2:
        y = np.argmax(y, axis=1)
    accuracy = np.mean(predictions==y)
    
    if not epoch % 100:
        print(f'epoch: {epoch}, acc: {accuracy:.3f}, loss: {loss:.3f}, lr: {optimizer.current_learning_rate}')
        
    loss_activation.backward(loss_activation.output, y)
    dense2.backward(loss_activation.dinputs)
    activation1.backward(dense2.dinputs)
    dense1.backward(activation1.dinputs)
    
    optimizer.pre_update_params()
    optimizer.update_params(dense1)
    optimizer.update_params(dense2)
    optimizer.post_update_params()


    

stream = [dense1.weights, dense1.biases, dense2.weights, dense2.biases]
with open("trained.nn", "wb") as h:
    pickle.dump(stream, h)
```

I know pickle isn't the best way, but it was easiest for me to program.

I double and triple checked that I had written the right code and I am sure I have written it correctly. I, however, doubt that because then it would be an error in the book, which aren't that common in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,64) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,64)

This error means that numpy can't [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) two arrays together. Broadcasting happens when you try to use arithmetic operations on two arrays of different shapes. In this case you're trying to add an array `bias_updates` of shape **(2, 64)** to an array `layer.biases` of shape **(1, 64)**.

I would recommand that you investigate why the array `bias_updates`  is of shape **(2, 64)** if you expect it to be of shape **(1, 64)**.

Given this part of your code:

```
bias_updates = (
        self.momentum * layer.bias_momentums
        - self.current_learning_rate * layer.dweights
    )
```

The shape of `bias_updates` comes from the shape of the array `layer.dweights` (numpy is silently broadcasting your arrays).

In general to debug this kind of errors you should write down the expected shapes of each of your arrays and check that they correspond at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed I should be multiplying by `layer.dbiases` instead of `layer.dweights` for that part